# How to apply a header image background?

Tags: html, css

I want the header to have an image for background. And I want that background image to have a 100% width and the rest of the image for the height (for whatever maintains aspect ratio for height).. and the header elements on top.

I tried to apply..

```
 header {
 Background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 }
```

but this makes the background stops right where the header elements stop (the navigation menu).. I want the background image to go all the way down till the image itself is finished..
I'm sorry if this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If you want the header's height to depend on the height of the background image, I'm afraid you are out of luck. Your only alternative would be javascript.

Comment: You want the background image to be larger than the header element?

Comment: I think your best bet is to specify the height of the header itself (in em) based on how big your image is. Then position the elements within that space. (When you say `background-size: 100%` that doesn't mean 100% of the size of the image, it means 100% of the size of the container.)

Comment: Yes. I want the header to be as high as the background image.. can't specify height pixels. cuz the image width would be 100%.. thus the height is suppose to change on whatever keeps image aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood this correctly the height of your header elements is less than the height of your picture.

```
header {
 Background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 height: <height of the image in pixels>px
}
```

This will make both the same height so that the image will not be cut off

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `z-index` property of the css.

CSS:

```
header
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: auto;
}
span
{
    z-index: 2;
}
img
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header><span>Your text here</span><img src='Your image.JPG'/></header>
```